# Good IDE for HTML

Tags: html, ide

I recently started to learn HTML from Code Academy. I have searched around a bit, but I have not been able to find a good IDE that closely resembles the one used in the Code Academy course. If anyone has any suggestions please tell me. I'm just looking for an IDE that resembles the one used in the Code Academy course.

Answer (score 2):

Most devs I know use Sublime Text, me personally I use a variety of tools depending on what I'm working on.

Which are good however are as always with this type of question subject to opinion.

What's good for me, may not suit you where as something I hate may be the perfect tool for you.

One bit of advice I will give you though, learn to code raw before you go looking for an editor that has all the bells and whistles and does stuff for you.

If your just starting out and your learning HTML, one of the worst things IMHO that you can do is to use an editor that writes the code for you.

I've trained a LOT of developers over the years, and by far the ones that always performed the worst, where the ones that used automated tools early in their training.

If you learn to write code, using a very minimalist editor then you'll quickly grow to understand what your writing better rather than thinking, "oh my editor will do this for me, and I can look it up later"

For me personally I have no problems logging into a Linux server at the command line and using something like midnight commander to live edit web pages in real time on a live web site :-)

If I want the bells and whistles, and I'm on windows then Visual Studio is often my tool of choice, if I'm on Linux at a desktop then often Net beans.

Every application has it's pros and cons the best way to find your perfect tool is to just try a few and see how you feel, it's like buying a new pair of shoes, unless you try them you'll never know if their going to fit or not.

Answer (score 0):

For HTML and such I really like Sublime Text (http://www.sublimetext.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Adobe has launched "Brackets". It's an amazing IDE. It used to be "Edge Code" before they renamed it. I would check this out before anything else. And it's free so, that's a plus.

http://brackets.io